# (Oracle) Data Pump compatibility?

Tags: database, oracle, export, datapump

I'm currently experimenting van different versions of Data Pump. (Oracle)
We have a bunch of dev oracle servers at work. Versions 11, 12, 18 and 19.

If I recall correctly, Oracle 19 should be backwards compatible with 18, 12 and 11.
I can successfully connect to the Oracle 12 server using the Oracle 19 client, but when I try to do a export using Datapump I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas? Shouldn't Data Pump also be backwards compatible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should

- export data using the **lowest** data pump export utility version involved (12c in your case)
- import data using the **target** database version's data pump import utility

For more info, see My Oracle Support (e.g. [Export/Import DataPump Parameter VERSION - Compatibility of Data Pump Between Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 553337.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=285773440979071&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=BULLETIN&id=553337.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=6rdi7cs8e_53))

Comment: Allright. So ideally I should also have the Oracle 12 client installed alongside Oracle 19 client?